# How can I find the domain of a function by switching variables as the subject?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $y=\ln(\sin^{-1} x)$ and I want to find the maximum domain. If I make $x$ the subject, I obtain $x=\sin(e^y)$ which I can analyze. $e^y>0$ so $-1<sin(e^y)<1$. But this is obviously not correct from a graphing on desmos. This is way possible? I am probably missing a few things that make it invalid.

Comment: You're approach of "making $x$ the subject" leads nowhere. In order for $\ln(\sin^{-1} x)$ to be defined (and real) you need $\sin^{-1} x>0$, when is that the case?

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I just thought it might work; I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $\log x$ is $(0,\infty)$. Thus the domain of $\log(\sin^{-1}(x))$ are those real numbers $x$'s of $[-1,1]$ such that $\sin^{-1}(x) > 0$. You know already about the range of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ which is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Thus you are looking at those real numbers $x$'s in $[-1,1]$ such that $\sin^{-1}(x)\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. This is precisely $(0,1]$. Thus $\text{Dom}_{\log(\sin^{-1}(x))} = (0,1]$ .